# Struggling to Store the SQL fetched results in an Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, fetch

I am struggling to store the sql fetched results in an array. I tried alot of suggested methods I found on the internet and I cant get it to work. I am obviously doing something wrong. This is the latest code I am testing atm:

```
// The following code is place after prepare() and mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $colDescription);

    $descArray = array();
    $i = 0;

    /* fetch values and store them to each variables */
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {          

        $fetch = $colDescription;
        $descArray[$i] = $fetch;
        $i++;
    }

    //For testing to see what echos in that array   
    foreach($descArray as $v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
```

In the above code, when I echo the array, only the last row of the table is outputted. So I think I am basically overlapping the values to the last row and its not really storing all the fetched values in an array. What am I doing wrong here? Can someone guide me please?

Comment: show output of your fetched data

Comment: Lets say the values that should be fetched is `1,2,3,4,5`. The output only shows `5` instead of echoing the full list `1,2,3,4,5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt quite get it to work with `mysqli` after trying for almost 2 days on this. So I have switched to `PDO` and I found that was **so much easier** to deal with array results that are fetched. This is what I have used now in the PDO method and it works like a charm:

```
// The following code is place after PDO prepare() and execute()

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        // do something with $row

            $description[] = $row['description'];
    }
```

You can see how easy it was and it just took a couple of lines to do this. It was like a nightmare when I was trying to achieve the same with mysqli and I dont even know if it was going to be possible. I tried so many methods with no luck. Even if it was possible with mysqli I am quite sure it would have taken a long windy and dirty looking code just to achieve something simple like this. **So its totally worth yet to make the switch to PDO.**

I hope this helps to someone stuck on this like me...

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand the value of `$colDescription` is overwriting. When you have it in the instruction

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $colDescription);
```

Now when you call it here

```
$fetch = $colDescription;
```

It gets the value initilized above so it is over writing. You need to do this.

```
unset($colDescription);
```

Before the loop so that it gets new value from `mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)`. So your code should be something like this

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $colDescription);

$descArray = array();
$i = 0;

unset($colDescription);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {          

    $fetch = $colDescription;
    $descArray[$i] = $fetch;
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($descArray);
```

Comment: If I add `unset($colDescription);` before the loop, it fails fetching the results for the first loop itself. I am getting this error when using the above code: `Undefined variable: colDescription in "$fetch = $colDescription;"`